# DNS Server - how to differentiate clients?

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, bind

I am running my own DNS server on a remote machine using Bind9. This server is currently only used by machines that are connected to the same router. The problem that I am having is that as the DNS server is used on a single network, all of the client machines that connect to it have the same external IP. So, when I am going through the logs, I can't differentiate which client machine each query or issue came from. I cannot move the DNS server locally so it is on the same network as the machines. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem - why would you need to differentiate between clients? Why can't you move the server to LAN when those are the only clients?

Comment: @Zac67 I can’t move the server to LAN as eventually it will serve multiple locations. In each location the client machines will be in a single network.

Comment: You could just as well use multiple local DNS servers. Also, using (VPN) tunneling between the LAN and the server might be an option. Otherwise you'll only see the NATed clients.

Comment: @Zac67 - tunnelling may be an option. Could I simply use a service like http://localhost.run/ or https://ngrok.com/ to make the server accesible from anywhere as a localhost?

Comment: Possibly, but I don't know them and we don't do recommendations around here.

Answer (score 1):

Clients behind a NAT cannot be differentiated on the basis of IP address. The authentication should be done at an upper (application) layer but the DNS protocol does not provide authentication mechanisms.

An intermediate layer such as `dnscrypt` or `TLS` (mutual TLS) can be used to authenticate clients.

In both cases, additional configuration on the client-side is required because most DNS clients do not support DoH/DoT or dnscrypt, or do not implement client certificates.

Have a look at dnscrypt-proxy for the client-side software.
It allows to provide client certificate [(see here)](https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy/blob/master/dnscrypt-proxy/example-dnscrypt-proxy.toml#L754) for mutual TLS or query_meta for dnscrypt [(see here)](https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy/blob/master/dnscrypt-proxy/example-dnscrypt-proxy.toml#L284).

Answer (score 0):

Simply configure your clients to query the DNS server over its IPv6 address.

With IPv6 each clients own IPv6 address should be retained and you avoid the whole NAT issue.

Comment: How am I able to force a client to query the DNS server over its IPv6 address? My current configuration doesn't rely on doing anything with the client devices but rather setting the DNS server on the router. Could I disable ipv4 on the router to force all devices to use ipv6?

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into query logging:

```
# vi /etc/named.conf
...
options {
        querylog yes;
}

...
logging {
        channel querylog {
                file "/var/log/querylog";
                severity debug 3;
        };
};
```

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-enable-bind-query-logging-to-find-out-whos-querying-a-name-server/

dnstop might also be an option:
The dnstop can read packets from the live capture device such as eth0 or a tcpdump savefile. You need to install this one where your caching DNS server or BIND 9/10 server is installed. You can see information about all DNS clients, DNS queries and much more with this tool. Maybe you differentiate by mac adress. `sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet` or `arp -a`

Comment: Thanks, I am already logging the DNS queries but all devices that use the DNS server are from the same network so the query logs show the same IP. Would Dnstop actually be able to differentiate between different clients even though they are on the same network?

Comment: nope sorry, you need to capture with tcpdump. `tcpdump -n -s 1500 udp and port 53` and analyze with whireshark

Comment: If the clients have the same IP, that means NAT is being used. This answer is wrong. Using **tcpdump** will not help either.